# proving $\lim_{n\to\infty} |b_n| =1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

How do I prove that given $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(a_n\cdot b_n\right)=1$, that if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(|a_n|\right)=1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(|b_n|\right)=1$? (I tried to say that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(|b_n|\right)$ is not 1, but got stuck; and also tried the direct proof by taking $\varepsilon/2$ for both but it didn't turn out well). Appreciated if someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first since $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n.b_n =1 \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_n.b_n|= |1|$$

and since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n| = 1 $ after certain point it will be nonzero.  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n| = 1 \implies \exists N \,\,\text{s.t} \,\, ||a_n|-1| < 1/2 \implies |a_n| \in(1/2,3/2)$$

we will use following statement

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p_n = L , \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} q_n = M (\neq 0) \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big(\frac{p_n}{q_n} \Big) = \frac{L}{M}$$
now $$|b_{N}| = \Big|\frac{a_N.b_N}{a_N}\Big| \implies  \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} |b_N| = \frac{\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}|a_N.b_N|}{\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} |a_N|} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$

Comment: hii, first of all thank you so much for the help, secondly, I didn't really get the last transition, how is that means that it leads to limbn=1?

Comment: @mathmagic added justification

Comment: this part ||=∣(*)/∣ I didn't get how is it leads to it?

Comment: no, what I meant is how the fact that ||∈(1/2,3/2) helps here with ||=∣(*)/∣ and therefore lim→∞||=1?

Comment: because consider following sequence $a_1 = 0 $ and $a_{n} = 1+\frac{1}{n}$ here $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 1$ but $b_1/a_1$ is undefined and hence we need to cross a particular point that gurantees that dividing by $a_n$ is a valid thing

Comment: thank you so much, and I got you. But why is lim→∞.=1⟹lim→∞|.|=|1|?